# Working on tmdb api on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api, themoviedb-api

I am continuing my journey in learning ruby and rails. I am currently working with the `tmdb gem` and trying to access and then return the results of my query.

In my `MovieController`, I have two methods: `search_tmbd` and `lookup_tmdb`. Here is what I have:

```
def search_tmdb
  #@movie = Tmdb::Movie.find(params[:search])
  @movie = Tmdb::Movie.lookup_tmdb(params[:search])
end

def self.lookup_tmdb(title)
  title = params[:search]
  @movie = Tmdb::Movie.find(title)
```

The user inputs the query in :search. When I do the query, I get this error:

> undefined method `lookup_tmdb' for Tmdb::Movie:Class.

I understand I may need to pass the values in an array, but how do I work this? This one below works for me in method `search_tmdb` and returns the title of the movie.

```
@movie = Tmdb::Movie.find(params[:search])
```

Answer (score 0):

Change definition to this

```
def lookup_tmdb(title)
  title = params[:search]
  @movie = Tmdb::Movie.find(title)
end
```

and thn call from other function like this

```
 @movie = lookup_tmdb(params[:search])
```

Comment: Thank you @Zahid! I got stuck there. I am getting the title from :search params. The title is being passed on my associated view now. How do I get the rating and released date then from the :search params and display that on my view?

Comment: I think that will be a different question, as this will require to show us your current code is view